# What are "effective" operators and what is meant by effective operators "at the LHC"?

Tags: operators, large-hadron-collider, effective-field-theory

My research supervisor told me to read about this topic but is currently on leave for the next two weeks. I believe it is related to effective field theory but please could someone elaborate on what they mean here or point me in the direction of some examples so that I can better understand?

Comment: by googling "effective operators LHC" I go a number of entries , the first https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02130

Comment: @annav I am aware of papers about effective operators such the one you linked: "Learning to pinpoint effective operators at the LHC: a study of the tt¯bb¯ signature", my question was what actually are effective operators?

Comment: I went on and searched from the abstract "standard model effective field theory"  and found this https://indico.mitp.uni-mainz.de/event/159/sessions/168/attachments/597/635/Peskin_Lecture_4.pdf .

Comment: @anna v. Indeed, Mike's talk is worth a hundred reviews of [SMEFT](https://conference.ippp.dur.ac.uk/event/630/contributions/3544/attachments/2995/3254/YTF10_January_2018.pdf)!